# Bit manipulation modify bits to include number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I am studying for an interview and I have been trying to understand this question for hours now:

> You are given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i
>   and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M
>   (e.g., M becomes a substring of N located at i and starting at j).

Could someone give a complete example and walk through what is actually required? Do i need to set the between i and j to form the value of M, or to actually the bits in M?

Is there some good tutorial on bits manipulation which explains the concepts?

Thank you!

Comment: That's an amazingly badly worded question.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still a beginner with Stackoverflow!

Comment: I didn't mean your question - I meant the question you were given. Yours is much better than theirs!

Comment: Does my answer cover everything you wanted to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be achieved using "[masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29)"

- creating a mask for the position i to j with each bit set to 1 using bitwise OR incrementally
- blank out the bits in N using bitwise AND and bitwise NOT of the mask
- select the bits from M using mask with bitwise AND
- copy bits in using bitwise OR

I know I've used hex in my example, but same principle applies, just easier to read.

Example

```
int n = 0x12345678;
int m = 0x55555555;

int i = 4; // assume right to left
int j = 15;

int mask = 0;
for (int pos = i; pos <= j; pos++) {
    mask = mask | (1 << pos);
}
System.out.println(String.format("mask is     0x%08x", mask));

int nCleared = n & ~mask;
System.out.println(String.format("clear n     0x%08x", nCleared));

int bitsFromM = (m & mask);
System.out.println(String.format("Bits from m 0x%08x", bitsFromM));

int nWithM = bitsFromM | nCleared;
System.out.println(String.format("n with m    0x%08x", nWithM));
```

Output

```
mask is     0x0000fff0
clear n     0x12340008
Bits from m 0x00005550
n with m    0x12345558
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say those 2 32-bit numbers are :-

```
M = "00010101010101010101010101010101";
N = "10101010100001010101100101011111";
i = 13;
j = 23;
```

They just want you to make N's 13th to 23rd bits the same as those in M.

I am counting the positions from the right-hand-side.

```
                                             23rd bit  13th bit
```

So,here, M's 13th to 23rd character = "000101010_____ 10101010101 ___010101010101";

```
is the mid-spaced 10101010101.
```

Hence, N must be 101010101___   10101010101   _____100101011111

or `N = 101010101   "10101010101"   100101011111`.